# Android Captioning manager returns invalid values

Tags: android, accessibility

I am trying to integrate with Android's built-in accessibility support for enhanced closed captioning.

If I try to access the values from the global settings, I am getting invalid negative integer values. For example,

> CaptioningManager.CaptionStyle.backgroundColor

returns

> -65536

Similarly,

CaptioningManager.edgeColor returns

> -16777216

This seems to be because of a hex conversion error in the native implementation.
Has anyone ever encountered similar issues and if so, how to resolve the same?

Answer (score 1):

In java, integers should be 4 bytes, and they represent an unsigned number.
Similarly, every color is represented as 4 bytes: Alpha, Red, Green and Blue respectively. This means, that every possible integer values will be a valid color value as well, even the negative numbers.

If you check the color class, even the predefined color values are initialized as integers:

```
public static final int BLACK       = 0xFF000000;
public static final int GRAY        = 0xFF888888;
public static final int WHITE       = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Your values are:

```
-65536 = 0xFFFF0000: RED.
-16777216 = 0xFF000000: BLACK
```